# Keep form input on route change AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Consider this example:

Main.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/page1', { templateUrl : 'page1.html' })     
                    .when('/page2', { templateUrl : 'page2.html' })
            })
        </script>

        <a href="#page1/">Page 1</a>
        <a href="#page2/">Page 2</a>

        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
Page 1: <input type="text">
```

page2.html

```
Page 2: <input type="text">
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/1BfO7KkHeMD3EpsULNGP?p=preview

Click on one of the links Page 1 or Page 2. Input something in the field and then click on the opposite link. The field is cleared. Is there a way to keep input? This is very useful if a user is posting a comment, but has to login before the changes can be saved. The user will be redirected to a login page, and after login be redirected back to the input page.

Comment: I think you may be interested in looking into HTML5's Storage interface: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#storage

Comment: you should look into angularjs 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `factory` (or `value`) to provide an simple way to share an object among controllers.

Here is an example:

```
myApp.factory('DataHolder', function (){
 return { myData: true, otherData: 'haha' };
});
// Or, with value
myApp.value('DataHolder', { myData: true, otherData: 'haha' });
```

And then, in your controllers:

```
myApp.controller('CtrlA', function ($scope, DataHolder){
  $scope.sharedData = DataHolder;
});

myApp.controller('CtrlB', function ($scope, DataHolder){
  $scope.sharedAsWell = DataHolder;
});
```

And, inside your views:

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlA">
  The other data is: {{sharedData.otherData}}, and mine is: {{sharedData.myData}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="CtrlB">
  <input type="text" ng-model="sharedAsWell.otherData"/>
</div>
```

Thanks to @ippi, he implemented it: [Plnkr implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/wI5aufzIFozvAQ3Zdz67)

Comment: Beat me to it, would use myApp.value('DataHolder',{}) though makes it a bit more readable for me.

Comment: And here op's plunk updated after Ivan's suggestion. http://plnkr.co/edit/wI5aufzIFozvAQ3Zdz67?p=preview

Comment: It just seems a little bit too cumbersome for just saving the state... http://plnkr.co/edit/a88cOYDVORDHQV3b5NGJ?p=preview

Comment: :((  What? AngularJS needs so much tweeking just to preserve state? I'm getting more and more disappointed in this technology, although I was thrilled when introduced to basics

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I usually default to a directive because you are injecting functionality into HTML elements rather than a service/factory. (But that's just personal preference). Anyway, here's a [WORKING FIDDLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/jwiLMthlohd5t8kQgiBa?p=preview) of a directive which relies on `localStorage`.

```
.directive( 'persist', ['$parse' , function( $parse ) {

    return {

        restrict: 'A',

        link: function( $scope, elm, attrs ) {

          var set = function( val, type ) {
            localStorage.setItem( type, val );
          };

          var get = function( type ) {
            return localStorage.getItem( type );
          };

          elm.bind( 'change' , function( e ) {

            set( this.value, elm.prop('id') );

          });

          var persistedVal = get( elm.prop('id') );

          if ( persistedVal ) {

            elm.val(persistedVal) 

          }

        }

      }
}]);
```